# django JWT asking for username/password

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I can successfully connect via CURL using the example posted in their documentation here:

http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#usage

The problem comes from trying to use Postman.  I set the authorization to Basic and put in my username/password and I get a 400 response with the following json:

```
{
  "username": [
    "This field is required."
  ],
  "password": [
    "This field is required."
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the username and password as part of the header send it as data in the body instead.  Here's an example of doing this with jQuery: http://jpadilla.com/post/73791304724/auth-with-json-web-tokens

Taking from the example the data you pass in the body should look like this:
`{ username: "admin", password: "abc123"}`

Comment: That got it thnx!  I'm assuming the header with the json is encoded when it passes to get the token? like how when I do Basic Authorization it hashes the username/password.

Comment: Basic authentication does a base 64 encode of your username and password I think.

Comment: found the following:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572707/rest-authorization-username-password-in-authorization-header-vs-json-body  Looks like it's neutral but preferred to use the HTTP standard auth.